# AFNetworking 2.0 JSON Vulnerability Protection

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking-2

i'm using AFNetworking 2.+ in my iOS app,
my server uses JSON Vulnerability Protection.

that makes my requests to the server "Half working".
meaning, i do get code 200 for my requests, but the request fails.
i can't parse the json.

I'm using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager and i set his Serializers like that:

```
    [self setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];
    [self setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializerWithWritingOptions:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted]];
```

i also tried that:

```
  [self setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];
  [self setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
```

didnt worked as well.

as far as i can tell, JSON Vulnerability Protection adds ")]}'," before the real json, as shown [here in angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

> JSON Vulnerability Protection A JSON vulnerability allows third party
>   website to turn your JSON resource URL into JSONP request under some
>   conditions. To counter this your server can prefix all JSON requests
>   with following string ")]}',\n". Angular will automatically strip the
>   prefix before processing it as JSON.
>
> For example if your server needs to return:
>
> ['one','two']
>
> which is vulnerable to attack, your server can return:
>
> )]}', ['one','two']

is there any way to handle that with the provided tools AFNetworking gives me?

Should i use a custom AFJSONRequestSerializer?

Thanks,

Shahar.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own...

i implemented

and added that method:

```
    -(id)responseObjectForResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response data:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error{

    NSString * jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if (jsonString && [jsonString hasPrefix:@")]}',"]) {
        jsonString = [jsonString substringFromIndex:@")]}',".length];
    }
    NSData *newData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:newData options:0 error:nil];
}
```

That fixed that.